# Google Maps Embed API Current Location as starting point with iframe

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, currentlocation, google-maps-embed

What i'm trying to do is set an address as destination and as the origin (starting point) I would like to put the current location of the device, but i cannot find anything on line that works with the iframe, all i found is to key current location as origin, but it doesn't seem to work, i also tried my location, current address and as i'm in italy i also tried with italian language, but all the same, any one know what's the correct command to put as origin so it will automatically get the user location as starting point

```css
.maps {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe allowfullscreen="" class="maps" frameborder="0" id="mapnavi" name="mapnavi" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?
origin=current+location
&destination=rome
&key=AIzaSyC-5CY9mOCeg5Y3IhPqi_Yd0-DZtWrJl-E">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current position using [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation#Getting_the_current_position) and then use it in latitude,longitude format.

For instance, it could look like https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?origin=40.871579,14.2878583&destination=Rome

Comment: yes, i just found out from google support that this cannot be done with i frame |Google Maps Embed API| and they are not planning to add this feature, must use JavaScript Maps API

Comment: Well in any case whether it's Javascript or Ember API you need a way to detect the current location and send it as a parameter. Neither of the APIs will understand anything like "current position", "my location" or "current address", because those values do not make any sense for a remote web server. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

One of those three parameters should work:

1. `&origin=lat,lang`
2. `&center=lat,lang`
3. `&ll=lat,lang`

Just add one of these parameters at the end of your src URL with your desired latitude & longitude.